# how to solve creating table issue in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
create table dept(
    Deptno integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY Departmentnumber,
    Dname varchar(20) NOT NULL Nameofdepartment,
    Loc varchar(10) NOT NULL Locationofdepartment
);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'Departmentnumber,Dname varchar(20) NOT NULL
> Nameofdepartment,Loc varchar(10) NOT' at line 1

Comment: Where is datatype declaration for column Departmentnumber,Nameofdepartment,Locationofdepartment?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this query?

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry i just misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you try to provide aliases to your `column` names, but you shouldn't, at least, not at the creation of the `table`:

```
create table dept(
    Deptno integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Dname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Loc varchar(10) NOT NULL
);
```

You can use those aliases in `select` commands, but not in `create table` commands.

See more about the syntax of `create table` in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry i just misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cant create an alias for columns when creating a table. Only when `select`-ing from it.

Remove the aliases and the query should work:

```
create table dept(Deptno integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,Dname varchar(20) NOT NULL ,Loc varchar(10) NOT NULL );
```

Comment: I want to display Departmentnumber,Nameofdepartment,Locationofdepartment also.

Comment: display them where? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @sanyadalal It's in your hand what type of datatype you want?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry i just misunderstood the question.